# IIS7.5/MVC Limit number of Managed Threads

Tags: iis-7.5, threadpool, limiting

I'm trying to limit the number of managed threads permitted by an ASP.NET MVC application running under IIS7.5 on Windows Server 2008.  I've attempted a number of different approaches but none seem to have worked as expected, I need to limit the number of threads as reported by

Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId

I also tried changing the   ASP/behaviour/limits properties/threads per processor limit but I still get new threads with a different thread id.

I really need a limited number of threads (say 5-10) with the same thread id for each one every time it's used.

At the moment I have the following config file

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <applicationPool maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU="1" maxConcurrentThreadsPerCPU="1" requestQueueLimit="5000"/>
    </system.web> </configuration>
```

pointed to by applicationhost.config

```
   <applicationPools>
        <add name="DefaultAppPool" enable32BitAppOnWin64="true" CLRConfigFile="C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\SCRWeb\Data\apppool.config">
            <processModel identityType="NetworkService" />
        </add>
```

And yet I still see more than 1 thread id in my application as reported by Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId

Any ideas?

Thanks